# Change input type of p:tree filter primefaces JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following code ( simplified ):

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" filterBy="#{node.year}">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

With this solution I am able to filter the treenodes by year, but I am not satisfied in the way the input is requested. By default it's inputText and I do not see a way to change it. I want to have it in a way it's done here in year column ( https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml ). But this solution does not work for tree filter.

Also, I have no control on the input type or placeholder.

This is how the filter input field looks now:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [TreeTable Filter](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/data/treetable/filter.xhtml?jfwid=417ce)?

Comment: @WoAiNii TreeTable filter does not seem to work for the Tree. In the TreeTable there are Columns inside which the custom filter can be inserted as <f:facet name="filter"...... > and it's sorting per column. In the Tree there are TreeNodes, so inserting filter per TreeNode makes no sense ( filter gets attached per each element ). I have tried inserting it after p:tree, but it does not get displayed. No matter if I use <p:inputText> with facet or without. Perhaps because each element of tree should be a treeNode. 

Changing from Tree to TreeTable is not an option.

Comment: Do you just need to convert the input filter into `type="number"` and add some style? Have you tried with some javascript?

Comment: @WoAiNii  Thanks for trying to help. In the end I just decided to define filtering functionality over controller class. Then I can use any input element I wish ( in my case I chose selectOneMenu )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my case was just implementing custom filter functionality using controller class. Took a while, but seems like that's the only adequate approach to have full control of the tree filter visual design.